# EventLog logging in a .Net Core 3.1 NuGet

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I have a NuGet package that cannot do normal logging via `ILogger`.  (If it does, and there is any kind of an error, it causes an infinite loop as it tries to log that there was an error, which fails and then trys to log that there was an error (which keeps repeating).)

We solved this issue by logging to the event log for this low level NuGet.  We used `System.Diagnostics.EventLog` and the `WriteEntry` method for this.

It all worked find until we tried to run it in a docker container.  Now it is throwing a `PlatformNotSupportedException` saying:

> EventLog access is not supported on this platform

A bit of googling says to use `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog` instead.  But this integrates with `ILogger`.  I don't want to force all the applications that use my NuGet to only support EventLog, I just need to be able to write directly to the event log for specific scenarios.  (I am not really sure what I want this to even do on a linux machine (does Linux even have an EventLog?)

**Is there a way to write directly to the event log in a way that will not error out on Linux (and maybe even log at the OS level somehow)?**

Comment: An "if config says x then log to console else log to EventLog" code, and config appropriately in the docker?

Comment: @CaiusJard - My issue is a bit lower level than that.  I can know when to log where.  But how do I get an instance of `Ilogger` that is configured with the only the EventLog provider when I need to log to only the event log, yet still be able to get an `Ilogger` that will have all the normal providers for all the other parts of my application?

Comment: How does your DI container know how to inject a IPersonRepository into PersonController but an IAccountRepository into AccountController?